# Grails spring security Oauth2

Tags: spring, grails, oauth-2.0, google-signin

I'm looking for advice with grails plugins:

- Spring Security OAuth2
- Spring Security OAuth2 - Google

I'm developing Grails 3.1.9 app and I need to add functional google login button.

1. I have added dependencies to my build.gradle.

   compile 'org.grails.plugins:spring-security-core:3.1.1'
   compile 'org.grails.plugins:spring-security-oauth2:1.1.0'
   compile 'org.grails.plugins:spring-security-oauth2-google:1.1.0'
2. Created application in google.
3. Created credentials:

   Added to  **Authorized JavaScript origins**.

   http://localhost:8089

   Added to **Authorized redirect URIs**.

   http://localhost:8089/oauth2/google/callback
4. Made configuration in application.yml.

---

```
grails:
    plugin:
        springsecurity:
            oauth2:
                providers:
                     google:
                         api_key: myKey
                         api_secret: mySecret         
                         successUri: /oauth2/google/success    
                         failureUri: /oauth2/google/failure   
                         callback: /oauth2/google/callback    
                active: true    
                registration:
                        askToLinkOrCreateAccountUri: /oauth2/ask 
                        roleNames: ['ROLE_USER']
```

5. Created new domain class with this command.

---

```
grails init-oauth2 myPackage User OAuthID
```

6. Added this to my User domain class.

   static hasMany = [oAuthIDs: OAuthID]
7. And at last added this to my login view.

---

```
<oauth2:connect provider="google" id="google-connect-link">Google</oauth2:connect>

Logged with google?
<oauth2:ifLoggedInWith provider="google">yes</oauth2:ifLoggedInWith>
<oauth2:ifNotLoggedInWith provider="google">no</oauth2:ifNotLoggedInWith>
```

---

The problem is, that after I click at to login via google, my page just refreshes and goes to /login/auth. There is no redirect to google authentification and code never gets to callback function in Oauth2.

Does someone know what am I doing wrong or what is missing? I'll be really thankful for any advice or shown example.

Comment: Can you show your redirect urls in the google web inspectors, seems that it's because this configuration: 
registration:
                        askToLinkOrCreateAccountUri: /oauth2/ask 
try to open this url, but better to catch your redirect pages before login.
Because redirect to login page 99% means that spring security denied some request

Comment: I hope this is what you mean. This link is supposed to redirect user to google server, but doesn't work.

`<a href="/spring-security-o-auth2/authenticate?provider=google" provider="google">Google</a>`

And that ` /oauth2/ask` is than used to redirect after application gets response from google server. At least that is as I think it works.

Comment: Did you check that "/spring-security-o-auth2/authenticate" url is open to world?

Answer (score 0):

Have you added OAuthID as plugin required parameter as following?

grails.plugin.springsecurity.oauth2.domainClass = 'myPackage.OAuthID'

Comment: Ask your doubts / query in a comments, don't answer the question on just assumptions.

Comment: Yes I have this in my application.groovy